# if the variable is not set, do not display the link

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Just want to check if the $url variable is not set in db, do not display the link on the view. Please check my code below and help me to find the mistake.

```
 <?php if ($url !== NULL) {echo ' <a href='.$url.' target="_blank">Visit Website</a>';} ?>
```

Comment: try replacing `if ($url !== NULL)` with `if ($url !== "")`

Comment: You have not said in your question how the mistake looks like, e.g. what expected you to happen and what happened instead? So what is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking for a NULL value, but not for example for an empty string. You should also quote your url:

```
// empty() will return TRUE for NULL, '', etc.
if (!empty($url)) {
  echo ' <a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are checking for a value from db, the value may not be null unless you specified it to be null. So,check whether the value is empty..

So, kindly replace

```
if ($url !== NULL) 
{
      echo ' <a href='.$url.' target="_blank">Visit Website</a>';
}
```

with

```
if ($url !== "")
{
      echo ' <a href='.$url.' target="_blank">Visit Website</a>';
}
```